# How to set inline CSS of element to default using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, inline-styles

I have simple function in which I change the default styling of text when a checkbox is checked, and change the styling back to default when checkbox gets unchecked.

The `terms.style = "";` should reset the style back to default, but for some reasons it doesn't, and I have absolutely no idea why. I know that the else scope is performed when checkbox gets unchecked, as I have tested it with manually entering different style.

```
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const checkBox = form.querySelector('input[name=termsCheckBox]');

checkBox.addEventListener('click', function(){
    const terms = document.getElementById('termsText');
    if (checkBox.checked){
        terms.style = "color: black; font-weight: normal";
    } else {
        terms.style = "";
    }
});//end of function
```

Comment: Your code work http://jsfiddle.net/d6rg1v25/

Comment: `element.style` is a read-only `Object`. Either use `element.setAttribute('style', 'color: black; font-weight: normal')` or use `element.style.cssText = 'color: black; font-weight: normal'`.

Comment: Sadly, neither of them helps.

Comment: Has your element some CSS in `style` attribute that you want to back to default?

Comment: Yes, the default style is color: red and font-weight: bold. I know I could insert these styles manually in js, but then it would be wrong from design perspective.

Comment: @CalvinNunes You should not change OP's code

Comment: didn't change... only added the HTML necessary to reproduce a [mcve]. The JS was the same only with a `console.log`

Comment: You added code from http://jsfiddle.net/d6rg1v25/ that i changed OPs css in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get inline CSS in `style` attribute of element using `getAttribute()` and store it in variable and on check/uncheck of checkbox insert and remove it from `style` attribute

```js
var checkBox = document.querySelector('#form input[name=termsCheckBox]'),
    terms = document.getElementById('termsText'),
    style = terms.getAttribute('style');

checkBox.addEventListener('click', function(){
  if (checkBox.checked)
    terms.style.cssText = "color:black; font-weight:normal";
  else
    terms.style.cssText = style;
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="checkbox" name="termsCheckBox">
  <textarea id="termsText" style="color:red; font-weight:bold">termsText</textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Why not just `terms.style = style;` in `else` statement ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style):

> Styles should not be set by assigning a string directly to the style
>   property (as in elt.style = "color: blue;")

Correct way would be:

```
checkBox.addEventListener('click', function(){
    const terms = document.getElementById('termsText');

    if(checkBox.checked){
        terms.style.color = "black";
        terms.style.fontWeight = "normal";
    }else{
        terms.style.color = "";
        terms.style.fontWeight = "";
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Dmitriy. I changed the code to yours, but sadly the style still doesn't reset.